# Print a specific row in cakephp 3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an item with descriptions in different languages and I want to print the  descriptions that belongs to the element in every language

This is my database:

> Descriptions
>   -id
>   -title
>   -description
>   -language_id
>   -multimedia_id
>
> Languages
>   -id
>   -language
>
> Multimedia
>   -id
>   -description_id
>   -web_file
>   -original_file
>   -category_id
>   -created
>   -created_by
>   -multimedia_type_id
>
> Relations
>   language_id -> id(Languages) multimedia_id -> id(Multimedia)

If i put this:

```
<? $this->Text->autoParagraph(h($multimedia->description->description)); ?>
```

it will only print the description with the same id in description_id(Multimedia) and id(Descriptions)

I want to print the description with the same id in multimedia_id(Descriptions) and id(Multimedia)

**Update**

My MultimediaTable

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('multimedia');
    $this->displayField('title');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Descriptions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'description_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);        

    $this->belongsTo('Languages', [
        'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'created_by',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);  

    $this->belongsTo('Countries', [
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);   

    $this->belongsTo('MultimediaTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'multimedia_type_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['language_id'], 'Languages'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['category_id'], 'Categories'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['created_by'], 'Users'));  
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['country_id'], 'Countries'));  
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['multimedia_type_id'], 'MultimediaTypes'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['description_id'], 'Descriptions'));
    return $rules;
}
```

**Update 2**

MultimediaController

```
    public function view($id = null)
{

    $multimedia = $this->paginate('Multimedia');

    $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Languages', 'Categories', 'Users', 'Countries', 'MultimediaTypes', 'Descriptions']
    ]);

    $this->set('multimedia', $multimedia);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);

    $languages = $this->Multimedia->Languages->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $categories = $this->Multimedia->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $users = $this->Multimedia->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $countries = $this->Multimedia->Countries->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $multimediaTypes = $this->Multimedia->MultimediaTypes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $descriptions = $this->Multimedia->Descriptions->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('multimedia', 'languages', 'categories', 'users', 'countries', 'multimediaTypes', 'descriptions'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure the data was queried correctly. How did you get the data?

Comment: There is still no information on the query you used to get the data

Comment: added my MultimediaController